# How to do user-defined columns in NoSQL and RDBMS

Tags: mongodb, nosql

We will soon be rewriting an application that will allow the end user to define objects and fields on those objects.

I am considering NoSQL for this task but am not familiar enough with it to know if this or an RDBMS is the best option.

I come from an MSSQL background and am familiar with options to handle this use case in an RDBMS: tacking on "CustomField1"-type fields onto tables; creating an Attribute table; using ALTER statements to alter the physical schema, etc. None of which sit well with me.

To complicate it further, data will artificially silo'd by a user's site. In other words, all the data will be in one database, but fields will be defined on a site level.

So I am starting to explore NoSQL (e.g. Mongo and Couch). I like the idea of storing a json document. It "feels" more natural for something like this. But this is new territory so a little scary. Really, this will be a "loose" schema. The objects themselves will be well known, but the fields could change. In RDBMS terms, we're talking 75+ table objects, including the main objects, lookup tables, many-to-many tables, etc.

My understanding is that NoSQL's primary benefits have more to do with scalability and persistence, which are not a concern here. This is an internal application and not a super-heavy load in terms of users. No micro services or anything like that. So I haven't seen much in terms of if/when to use NoSQL when handling user-defined columns or even the fundamental differences in tables vs documents approach. Most of the stuff I've read is about performance and scalability.

Concerns:

- Reporting. This is a sales app and getting aggregated data out is a must. We use SSRS and Tableau.
- We will be using a .Net Core api. Historically we use ORM's (NHibernate, Entity Framework). I'm not married to this approach but need to know the "equivalent" in a NoSQL environment.
- Performance. Our current stack--.Net 4.5, NHB, MSSQL--just isn't great for various reasons. How is NoSQL on pulling large object graphs? How do you (or do you not) pull back "part" of a json document?
- Mass updates. Like in MSSQL I can do a UPDATE mytable SET col1 = 'foo' WHERE col2 = 'bar'. Just want to make sure the same thing exists and it is performant in NoSQL!

BTW, I'm hardly getting any views on this on the software recommendation site. I don't know if that's less trafficked site or what. But I'm on SO enough to know this is a good place to ask this.

So, basically my question is: in light of the above concerns, is NoSQL the best database option for user-defined fields? Why or why not? Or should I stick with MSSQL.

Thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged with sql server since you say you don't want to use sql server?

Comment: @SeanLange clarified the question. not opposed to mssql. just want to know if nosql is better for the purpose of dynamic fields.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering wrt mongodb database,

Answering your concerns,

1. Yes, mongodb supports aggregation operation and mongodb enterprise comes with BI connector, using that you can connect to BI tools like Tableau and excel
2. if you are going for MongoDB atlas(cloud version of Mongodb), it provides mongodb stitch, which will expose your mongb data as rest apis.
3. Yes, you can pull back part of the json document using $project operator, it will improve your performance
4. Yes, you can do mass updates like MSSQL using db.collection.updateMany() function.

Coming back to original question, since no sql databases are schema less, you don't need to modify the schema, whenever a new field gets added to a collection(table).